# Verifying the certificate given in SNS message SigningCertURL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

The [docs for SNS signature verification](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.verify.signature.html) mention that you need to download the cert given by `SigningCertURL` to check that the signature is valid.

What steps should I take to make sure the certificate there is valid (and that it doesn't belong to evil.example.com)?

The docs say "Verify the certificate was received from Amazon SNS". What needs to be checked specifically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verifying the source of the certificate means verifying that the hostname in the provided URL is a valid `sns.${region}.amazonaws.com` endpoint and then using an HTTPS user agent that doesn't have SSL certificate verification disabled.

Most people know that in HTTPS, the web server's certificate is used in the process of encrypting the connection.  Fewer people realize that other things are happening, too: the certificate is signed by a trusted certificate authority, establishing a chain of trust, and the certificate contains the hostname of the server presenting it in the Subject and/or Subject Alternative Name fields.  A mismatch on the hostname can mean the server is an impostor, as would a signature not matching a trusted CA root or intermediate (browsers/user agents already know about the identities of the trusted CAs).  User agents validate this automatically, typically, unless you take stres to disable it (such as by using the `--insecure` option with `curl`. Don't do that).

By verifying that the URL is sensible and then using HTTPS to get the cert itself, you are verifying that you're fetching the cert from a server presenting a valid certificate identifying a valid and acceptable hostname, thus not an impostor or untrusted source.

Note that you'll want to cache the cert in memory once you get it once.  They rarely change.

Comment: So just to clarify, you're saying I should check the URL itself (and check that  I'm using a valid HTTPS connection), rather than check the properties of the downloaded certificate itself?

Comment: Correct.  What's in the cert could be forged, but if you confirm that you're getting it from SNS directly with those two techiques then the only way it could be forged would be for SNS itself to be compromised.

Comment: Caveat. I don't know if I was conflating this with something else (perhaps the instance identity document validation certificate) or if SNS has changed the way they provision these certificates, but it appears that these certs are indeed signed by and candidates for even more complete validation up through a Symantec CA.   I need to test this further, but my answer may not tell the complete story -- but even if this is the case, the cert merely having a valid trust chain isn't a sufficient test.  The subject of the cert would need to be verified as being official SNS.